# How to write a class factory that produces classes with different Meta classes

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, metaclass

I'm using Django with Django rest framework. I would like to create a class factory which produces serializer classes with different `Meta` classes.

```
class MarksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Marks
        fields = (
            'english',
            'maths',
            'science',
        )
        read_only_fields = (
            'maths',
        )
```

I would like to vary the read only fields and the fields tuples according to the argument passed to the factory. Please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `type` to [construct classes dynamically](http://jfine-python-classes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/type-name-bases-dict.html#type-name-bases-dict).

First, construct your Meta class:

```
Meta = type('Meta', (object,), {'model': Marks, 'fields': fields, 'read_only_fields': 'read_only_fields'})
```

Then use this Meta class to construct your serializer class:

```
MySerializer = type('MarksSerializer', (serializers.ModelSerializer,), {'Meta': Meta})
```

That should give you the tools required to make your factory function.

Another option would be to override the `__init__` method of the serializer and modify the fields when the serializer is initialized. There's an example of this in the [DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields).

Comment: I'm not able to call any methods or access any fields inherited from `serializers.ModelSerializer` using the first method -

Comment: Did you get the first approach to work. I think you might need to use DRF's metaclass instead of `type`. First import it: `from rest_framework.serializers import SerializerMetaclass`. Then do `MySerializer = SerializerMetaclass('MarksSerializer', (serializers.ModelSerializer,), {'Meta': Meta})`.

Comment: Didn't test the behaviour fully, don't know if it was making the appropriate fields readonly, In the end I decided to go with the second method since it's documented in the DRF doc,  but I'm having trouble with that. I'm doing in the parent class __init__: 
`for field_name in allowed_fields[role]['read_only_fields']:
                self.fields[field_name].read_only = True`
But these fields aren't becoming readonly.BTW, is this supposed to be a separate question ?

Comment: I think you'd be better asking that as a separate question.